# javascript show variable in html

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a money display for a form which I am making, now I found this script on the web: http://jsfiddle.net/QQGfc/ And I'm trying to implement it into my code like this: (but it's not displaying the text.)

```
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = "My new text!";
</script>
```

With this in the body

```
<?php
include'includes/header.php'; 
include'includes/slider.php'; //carousel
?>


<h2>Contact Information</h2>


<div id="MyEdit">
    This text will change
</div>
```

Ay idea whats going wrong?

Comment: In how far is the code snippet you posted similar to the fiddle you referenced?

Comment: You need to include your script element below your `myEdit` DIV. Or, use document.onready or window.onload to execute the script when the document is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You imply that the JavaScript is in the `<head>`.

When it runs, the `<body>` hasn't been parsed, so the element you are trying to modify does not exist.

Either:

- Move the script to after the `<div>` you are trying to modify.
- Wrap the script in a function and call that function after the `<div>` exists (e.g. by [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) it as a `load` event handler).

Comment: I'm still new to this language :P Had no idea that it had to be below!
Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hmm does this work with variables which I declared before? I want to diplay the value of the money.

Comment: The value of what? There's nothing about "the money" in the question. You might want to try-it-and-see and then ask another question if you don't get the results you expect.

Comment: The result is great, just asking a followup :P

I'm trying to display a variable in the div. The variable is defined in the head above `price = 150` so I'd like it to say "150"

Answer (score 0):

you should do it after the DOM is completely loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = "My new text!";
    });
</script>
```